# Creating a table using a range imported from a text file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm importing a text file into Excel and then trying to turn that range into a table.

When you try to create the table manually you get the prompt:

> Your selection overlaps one or more external data ranges. Do you want to convert the selection to a table and remove all external connecitons?

If you select Yes it works.

If you try to delete the named range from the name manager, then when you get the range selection box and click OK nothing occurs, there are no errors the box doesn't go away nothing happens at all. Removing the connections does not fix this either but the named range seems to be what actually causes it.

When you try to create the table through code you will get:

> error 1004: A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells or another table.

```
Sub TestNameConnDelete()
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In ActiveWorkbook.names
        item.Delete
    Next item

    For Each item In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        item.Delete
    Next item
End Sub

Sub TestTableCreate()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Locked = False
        .ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)), , xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

The only solution I have found is to copy the whole thing into another sheet as values and make the table there. I have tried multiple text files and they all cause the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to work with a [`QueryTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable), something along the lines of

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
```

Perhaps a helpful snippet from the [`QueryTable.ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.listobject) documentation:

> If you import data by using the user interface, data from a web query or a text query is imported as a `QueryTable` object, while all other external data is imported as a `ListObject` object.
>
> If you import data by using the object model, data from a web query or a text query must be imported as a `QueryTable`, while all other external data can be imported as either a `ListObject` or a `QueryTable`.

So for text queries, it seems you are stuck to deleting the `QueryTable`, and then creating the `ListObject` as you are currently doing.